# TFS 2010 migration from one server to another

Tags: team-foundation-server

We have followed- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869(v=vs.100).aspx every steps of this extremely poorly worded article.

We are not able see Dashboards of SharePoint projects. In some cases(mostly scrum projects, i guess), i get "The Webpage can not be found".

In other cases- Unable to refresh data for a data connection in the workbook. 
Try again or contact your system administrator. The following connections failed to refresh:

TfsOlapReport

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the user you are using for creating Team Project has TFS rights on TFSOlapReport.
You can check it taking the Reporting Server url in your administration TFS console (something similar to "http://YourReportServer/Reports"). 
Once you get that, you can check in TFSOLAPReportsDS and TFSReports under security option whose are those user with TF Content Manager rights.